# VBA Code using Array to drag down formula till last row

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

I Have below code that drags formulas in range X3 - AK3 till its last row. I have to do the same operation in 4 other sheets so I think this is what making my code slower and I read array will help to do it faster. Below is my bit of code, can someone help to convert it to work with array.

````
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Range("X3:AK3").Autofill Destination:= Range("X3:AK" & Lastrow)```
````

Comment: Yes, I tried to learn what an array is and how it works in VBA. But unable to figure out proper line of code to drag or fill formula.

Comment: You can enter a formula in the range.  For example, `Range("X3:AK" & Lastrow).Formula = "Sum(A3:W3)"` . But then also, it will take time for calculation for huge data. If you have array of the same size of the range. Then `Range("X3:AK" & Lastrow).Value = array` should work

Comment: If you turn off screenupdating and set calculation to manual while autofilling (don't forget to reset calc to auto), that may be enough to give you acceptable performance.

Comment: Sharmila, similar questions have been covered many times is the past. Array is a fast option but you will lose your formulas. `.Formula` as suggested by Naresh is also a good option. If you want to stick to your method then set the events as Tim mentioned above but remember that when using events, it is advisable to use proper error handling and there you reset the events else your events will not reset to what it was before you changed it when and if an error occurs...